# Adding new row is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this jQuery script to create dynamic table to enter data of multiple address I have problem when I want add new row is not adding new row  to my table can someone help me ?my console told me this message

> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard
>   event.preventDefault() instead. GET id: 1 | $id :street_01

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="address_table" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Street</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Province</th>
                    <th>PostalCode</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="street_01" maxlength="255" required /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="city_01" maxlength="255" required /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="province_01" maxlength="255" required /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="postalCode_01" maxlength="7" required /></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="button" value="Add Row" id="add_AdressRow" />
    </div> <!--/container-->
    </form><!--/form-->

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
// GET ID OF last row and increment it by one
    var $lastChar = 1, $newRow;
    $get_lastID = function () {
        var $id = $('#address_table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("name");
        $lastChar = parseInt($id.substr($id.length - 2), 10);
        console.log('GET id: ' + $lastChar + ' | $id :' + $id);
        $lastChar = $lastChar + 1;
        $newRow = "<tr> \
                    <td><input type='text' name='street_0" + $lastChar + "' maxlength='255' /></td> \
                    <td><input type='text' name='city_0" + $lastChar + "' maxlength='255' /></td> \
                    <td><input type='number' name='province_0" + $lastChar + "' maxlength='11' /></td> \
                    <td><input type='text' name='postalCode_0" + $lastChar + "' maxlength='255' /></td> \
                    <td><input type='button' value='Delete' class='del_ExpenseRow' /></td> \
                </tr>"
        return $newRow;
    }

    // ***** -- START ADDING NEW ROWS
    $('#add_AdressRow').bind("click", function () {
        if ($lastChar <= 9) {
            $get_lastID();
            $('#expense_table tbody').append($newRow);
        } else {
            alert("Reached Maximum Rows!");
        };
    });

    $(".del_AdressRow").bind("click", function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $lastChar = $lastChar - 2;
    });
```

Comment: We don't have the javascript code.

Comment: i bet you it's in that script.js file

Comment: sorry forget to add code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the id selector on javascript is #expense_table and on html is #address_table.just change it to  address_table

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$get_lastID();
$('#expense_table tbody').append($newRow);
```

to this:

```
$('#expense_table tbody').append($get_lastID());
```

For the console error, just change event.returnValue to event.preventDefault();